# DC Buck Converter for more than 3A

Tags: batteries, dc, buck, 5v

I want to use an Arduino Nano to controll an LED strip using an WS2812B IC. The strip takes 5V at 3.6A. I want to power the arduino and the strip using two 18650 Li-ion batteries (LGDBHE41865), which can deliver up to 20A per cell. These batteries are unprotected and I think I need a protection board, that allows enough current to flow. However, I was unable to find one. It would be nice if someone can point me in the right direction. In addition I need a buck converter to step down the voltage from the batteries (2*3.7=7.4V) to 5V. I found some, but all of them have 3A limit which isn't enough for me, so I need some suggestions there too.

I'm new to this stuff, so maybe there's a simple solution I can't think of. 
It would be nice if someone can tell me how to do this right. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered buying a USB power bank? That has the cells, charge controller and 5V regulator all built in.  Most don't have a 3A output, but some do. They usually also have the added advantages of overcurrent protection, state of charge indication, and of course you can be fairly confident they are done right - LiIons are not forgiving of mistakes.

Comment: I had no trouble finding 5A (and larger) buck converter modules on aliexpress.  prices start below $2

Answer (score 1):

> I found some, but all of them have 3A limit which isn't enough for me,
>   so I need some suggestions there too

A couple of buck regulators that appears suitable: -

[image]

[image]

Don't start quibbling on cost, if you want something cheap and possibly unreliable and noisy go ebay.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TI Web Bench Designer.  It will give you like 50 circuit diagrams that meet your criteria.

http://www.ti.com/

Just enter your required input voltage range, output voltage and output current and hit go.  Its as easy as that.

The LM25085 comes up as a good choice.

You can select...

1)  Input voltage ragnge.

2)  Output voltage.

3)  Output current.

4)  Ambient operating temperature.

5)  Prioritize between smaller design area, lower cost, or higher efficiency (or abalance between those).

6)  Required efficiency

7)  Required maximum footprint

8)  Maximum allowed BOM cost

9)  Various other power supply features

The TI Web Bench designer will give you...

1)  A list of multiple auto-generated designs that meet your criteria.

2)  A complete schematic for each design.

3)  A bill of materials.

4)  For some designs you can actually have a PCB fabricated for the design and ordered through Digikey.

5)  An analysis of the whole circiut.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to buy something off the shelf and don't mess with making a custom PCB. If you can tolerate the heat, try a linear regulator module. You would generate 2.4V*3.6A = 7.2W worth of heat through it, a little more if you are also powering the Arduino. If you don't like wasting power, I would suggest a switching regulator module. Something like [this](https://www.pololu.com/product/2851) step down module from Polulu would work. Additionally would look in the drone / RC hobbyist sites like Hobbyking because drone motors require similar if not high current draws compared to your application.